# Я пытаюсь зайти на сайт c Python, выдает ошибку

Tags: python, сеть, обработка-ошибок, urllib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, у меня к вам вопрос. Я пытаюсь зайти на сайт (пароль, логин, ясно ..) и выводить из него код страницы. Так вот, в чем же проблема? Через раз выдает ошибку (я думаю из-за того, что я не выхожу из страницы) и я не знаю как исправить эту ошибку.

Вот фото ошибки и сам код

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://3link1/'
username = 'admin'
password = 'admin'

p = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
p.add_password(None, url, username, password)

handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
page1 = bytes.decode(page)
print(page1)
```

Ошбка: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

Comment: Лучше в вопросе укажите текст и стек ошибки

Comment: Цитируйте текст ошибки текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: "Так вот, в чем же проблема? Через раз выдает ошибку (я думаю из-за того, что я не выхожу из страницы) и я не знаю как исправить эту ошибку."

Comment: я не понимаю в чем проблема. поэтомку и не могу ее цитировать